# Export SQL server data into a CSV file

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, webforms

I've just taken care of a project that requires converting data from the old website (built in C# web form) to the new one (using PHP).

In the old database, there is a product table contains 1600 products that I need to export into a CSV file then import to the new database but I have no idea to do that.

I can access the current server but I don't see any **.cs** file (code-behind file). I also have no idea how to export that table to a CSV file using myLittleTools (The SQL server management tool that Plesk provide).

Can any have me please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. This is a tool provided by MSSQL .

Reference links here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/get-started-with-this-simple-example-of-the-import-and-export-wizard

You can export to either or excel or directly map two tables of different databases and transfer data

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MyLittleAdmin site](http://www.mylittleadmin.com/yafnet/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=126) you can opent the table to view the data and export it form there.

Comment: There is no export function in MyLittleAdmin site

Comment: according to their website there is:

http://www.mylittleadmin.com/en/features.aspx

"Database content management
myLittleAdmin includes a powerful editable datagrid that allows editing and deleting records while browsing your data. MyLittleAdmin also offers the possibilities to export data into XML, XLS and CSV formats."

Comment: I've been going through something similar to what the OP is going through, and have tried all export options myLittleAdmin offer.

The "CSV" export is not CSV. it's a semi-colon delimited file format, but there's no way to tell a semi-colon delimiter from a semi-colon in a data field because they don't double quote text strings. Also, no headers, so you don't know what each column is called.

the "XLS" export is not XLS. it's like the XML part from an XLSX group file, but it's definitely not XLS. I can't get LibreOffice to open it, for example.

the "XML" option - XML. yuck.